# How to return result with the list of errors from function

Tags: c#, design-patterns, function, functional-programming

I have faced difficulties trying to return a result combined with the set of errors from function call.

I have started from the following approach

```
List<String> errors;
bool result = Obj.GetResult(out errors, int id);
```

The second step was to introduce new class

```
public class OperationResult
{
  public bool Result {get;set;}
  public List<string> Errors {get;set;}

}
```

But then the dirty code started to appear inside the GetResult method.

For example

```
public OperationResult GetResult(int id)
{
  if (id == 0)
  {
    return new OperationResult { Result = false, Errors = {"Error"}};
  }

  if (id < 400)
  {
    var result = new OperationResult { Result = false, Errors = {"Error"}};
    if (id >200)
       result.Errors.Add("Error");
    return result;
  }
}
```

Then I've started to worry not allowing result user to edit the result they get.

I have extracted interface from the OpearationResult class which was able only to read data.

Now I'm want to add result builder class...

And at this point I've started to thinking that I'm doing something wrong. Trying to reinvent the bicycle, or just creating problems out of the air.

Please give me an advice, how to handle all this stuff.
I am also curious how this is handled in the functional programming languages. (I mean immutability)

Comment: Any reason you're not using Exceptions?

Comment: Never liked exception overuse, the reason maybe the same as one which forced MS to abandon exception based ui validation.

Comment: You could only over-use the throw statement.  Returning an exception as an object is fine.  Methods that return a bool are otherwise quite evil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a time to start throwing exceptions.
In his book [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882), Robert Martin talks about the confusion and lack of readable code when you do something like:

```
CustomResult result = myUser.CanLogOn();
```

Because it would appear from reading the code that CanLogOn should simply return a bool indicating if the user is allowed to log on, but now it's getting a custom result object that has error codes etc.  This will cause you to further pollute your code with things like

```
if(result.Result)
   LogOn();
```

instead of

```
if(myUser.CanLogOn())
   LogOn();
```

or even better

```
myUser.LogOn()
```

and let it decide if it can or not.

This is a simplified example, because I'd assume apart from a DB exception there isn't a lot of possible errors that can occur in a CanLogOn() method.

While you shouldn't use exceptions for normal flow, they are there, in part, to prevent this pattern of output values, and error codes on the return, and needing to know the difference between a return code of 200 and 402 and -134.

It will make your code cleaner, easier to read, and might prompt you to examine if you really need all those exceptions, and if so, is this method the best place to throw them from.

Comment: The side effect here is that code is futher polluted! The CanLogon method could own and return all the issues regarding failure. This in turn is uniformly communicated to the user and calling code.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions were invented to prevent the mess you're getting into here.

What about other methods that don't return `bool` ?

I could think of other problems with your approach but the main one would be: It's a lot more work (vs throwing) and it's going to be so very easy to make a mistake with this. Error while reporting Error ...

Answer (score 1):

I think the protection level you need can be accessed via the `readonly` keyword:

```
internal class OperationResult
{
    public OperationResult(bool result, List<string> errors)
    {
        Result = result;
        Errors = errors;
    }

    readonly bool Result { get; set; }
    readonly List<string> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

With this modifier, the 2 attributes can only be set inside constructors, so no way for your clients to modify them. So to use them as you like, just modify a bit your program: set your list of errors, then build create your `OperationResult` object:

```
public OperationResult GetResult(int id)
{
  if (id == 0)
  {
    return new OperationResult(false, new List<string>{"Error"});
  }

  if (id < 400)
  {
    var errors = new List<string>{"Error"};
    if (id >200)
       errors.Add("Error");
    return new OperationResult(false, errors);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to provide a contemporary take on the problem (C# 7 and above) as I faced a similar challenge in [DomainResult](https://github.com/AKlaus/DomainResult) NuGet package that has 50+ extension methods to return a result along with errors.

In your case `OperationResult` class would have these properties (note read-only error collection)

```cs
IReadOnlyCollection<string> Errors { get; } // Collection of error messages if any
bool IsSuccess { get; }                     // Flag, whether the current status is successful or not
DomainOperationStatus Status { get; }       // Current status of the domain operation: Success, Error, NotFound
```

And from here you've got 2 options:

1. Have a generic `OperationResult<T>` that extends the one above by adding `T Value { get; }` property.
2. Return [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple) from methods, like `(T, OperationResult)`.

Now spice it up with multiple extension methods, e.g.

```cs
// Successful result with an int
(value, state) = OperationResult.Success(10);        // value = 10; state.Status is 'Success'
// The same but wrapped in a task
var res = OperationResult.SuccessTask(10);           // res is Task<(int, OperationResult)>

// Error message
OperationResultres = OperationResult.Error("Ahh!");  // res.Status is 'Error' and res.Errors = new []{ "Ahh!" }
// Error when expected an int
(value, state) = OperationResult.Error<int>("Ahh!"); // value = 0, state.Status is 'Error' and state.Errors = new []{ "Ahh!" }
```

Check out the samples at https://github.com/AKlaus/DomainResult. It all yours.

Comment: This is the best answer and should me marked as such. A flexible Result pattern is what the OP requested